# Updating periodically with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex, moya

I use the following setup to retrieve objects (e.g. GitHub issues) from an API. This works fine.

```
let provider: RxMoyaProvider<GitHub>
let issues: Driver<[IssueViewModel]>

init(provider: RxMoyaProvider<GitHub>) {
    self.provider = provider
    issues = provider.request(.Issue)
              .mapArray(Issue.self, keyPath: "issues")
              .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
              .map { (models: [Issue]) -> [IssueViewModel] in
                  let items = models.map {
                      IssueViewModel(name: $0.name,
                          description: $0.description
                      )
                  }
                  return items
              }
}
```

Now I'd like to periodically update the list of issues (e.g., every 20 seconds). I thought about an `NSTimer` to accomplish this task, but I guess there might be a clean(er) solution (i.e. in a Rx manner) that I didn't think about.

Any hint in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is very similar to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37447140/343299).

You should use `timer` and then `flatMapLatest`:

```
Observable<Int>.timer(0, period: 20, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .flatMapLatest { _ in
        provider.request(.Issue)
    }
    .mapArray(Issue.self, keyPath: "issues")
    // ...
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Given that .Issue expects a parameter (e.g., `.Issue(id: issueId)`), how to reference this in `flatMapLatest` (`issueId` is a stored property)?

Comment: use `.flatMapLatest { [weak self] _ in` in the block and then `self?.issueId`.

Comment: Hello from the future! You might wish to use `concatMap` if you want to process the requests in order.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for `interval` operator.
Here is a loop example for `interval` that will keep printing "test" every second. 
Link to documentation: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html

```
    var driver: Driver<String> {
        return Driver<Int>.interval(1.0).map { _ in
            return "test"
        }
    }
    driver.asObservable().subscribeNext { (variable) in
        print(variable)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do you apply this to a `Driver`?

Comment: It looks like interval works with `Drivers` as well. I've updated previous example

Comment: Great, but how can I apply this to my specific example?